# Incorrect Definitions of NP

Tags: algorithms

I was solving problems related to P and NP where I encountered the following problem:
Given a standard definition of NP,

if x belongs to L then there exists y such that |y| <= |x|^d and A(x, y) = 1;

if x does not belong to L then for every y with |y| <= |x|^d we have A(x, y) = 0.

1. what is the new class formed when we don't include the second statement?(x belongs to L)
2. what is the new class formed when we don't include the first statement? (x does not belong to L)

   I am well versed with the definitions of P and NP but unable to figure out how to determine and prove  these new classes.

Comment: Cross-posted: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3916655/14578, https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/132367/755.  Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068).

Answer (score 1):

If we don't include the second statement, then there is no restriction on what we do when x is not in $L$, so consider the program:

```
A(x,y):
  return 1
```

And this shows that any language $L$ is in our new language class. A similar construction works for 2. See if you can figure it out now!

Comment: I figured that out. But if x does not belong to L, then the verifier program will never terminate right?

Comment: This algorithm terminates as all it does is return 1 (no while loops or anything).

 If x is not in L, the verifier program still just returns 1. It is wrong, yes, but there are now no restrictions on what to do when x is not in L, so this is fine

Comment: This is where I was getting stuck. I was confused if it terminates or not, and if terminates what would be the output by the verification algorithm.

Comment: The output of our verifier is always 1. Does that make sense, or am I not understanding what you mean by "verification algorithm"?

Comment: What if we change the definition of NP like this - for every x belongs to {0,1}* there exists y such that x belongs to L, iff y = O(x^d) and A(x,y) = 1.  @Isaac

Comment: This same algorithm works, yes? As any y will work because A(x,y) = 1 for all x and y and thus there exists a y.

Comment: So in this new definition, x does not matter if it belongs to L or does not belong. The verifier will give A(x,y) = 1 for all x and y? @Isaac

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/116491/discussion-between-anony-std-and-isaac-browne).